# Access SQL query using iff statement

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table like below. I'm trying to sort data based on code column. If length of the code lessthan or eqaual to 5 ,then code should be sort as it is, if code length is >5 then remove 2 digits from code while sorting.

```
   sno  Code
    1   17750
    2   17775
    3   63204A06
    4   63204A07
    5   F16D078
    6   8186
    7   8100
    8   63513A52
```

My sql query is

```
    SELECT sno, iif(Len([Code])<=5,[Code],Mid([Code],3)) AS Codeno FROM table1
```

And more condition to satisfy with code column is, if code is starts with letter then it should remove only that letter (in starting position). Sorting result should looks like

```
    sno Code

    1   17750
    2   17775
    3   204A06
    4   204A07
    5   16D078
    6   8186
    7   8100
    8   513A52
```

How do i specify that in same iff condition in a above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you leave the letter in if [code] is 5 characters or less:

```
SELECT sno, 
iif(Len([Code])<=5,[Code],iif(ASCII([Code])>57,Right([Code],Len([Code])-1),Mid([Code],3)))
AS Codeno FROM table1
```

Comment: Thanks. Working perfect with small correction in ASCII. In Access sql it is taking as ASC.